# Put an image over adsense

Tags: html, css, adsense

How can I put an image over Google adsense? I want track user clicks, so, when someone click on an ads, I want handle onclick method.

```
.ad-alert {
    width: 728px;
    height: 400px;
    background: #cccccc;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
    z-index: 6000;
}

<div class="ad-alert" onclick="alert('test');">
    <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
        style="display:block; text-align:center; z-index: 4998"
        data-ad-layout="in-article"
        data-ad-format="fluid"
        data-ad-client="ca-pub-1543026956912231"
        data-ad-slot="207185479"></ins>
    <script>
        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>
</div>
```

But isn't working, the .ad-alert is behind the ads, and not in front as I want. Can you help me? Thank you!

Comment: did u try with z-index:6000 !important; ?

Comment: Yes! Google ads keep showing in front and not behind.

Comment: but did u know it violates adSense policy?

Comment: Yes, I know it! But I'm being paid to create this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your styles for `.ad-alert` are missing `position: absolute` which is needed if you want to leverage the `z-index` value.

```
.ad-alert {
  position: absolute;

  width: 728px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #cccccc;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  z-index: 6000;
}
```

You can learn more about `absolute` positioning here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: Hi, thank you! But the ads still showing in front of .ad-alert, not behind! :(

Comment: You could try using dev tools to inspect the ad to see if it's using a `z-index` as well. Then you could try bumping yours up higher.

Comment: I already tried it, changing on dev tools console the value of z-index of both elements, the google ads still always showing in the front, I don't know why!